# POST request with JSON body do not deliver to the endpoint in springboot microservice architecture

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I'm building my first springboot microservice project and I'm trying to POST a request to a subscriber service, which requires a body in json format and has to include a name and uri for the subscription service to reach the subscriber, this is the class which implement the POST request,

```
public class Registration{

public static void postRegistration(){

final String registrationUrl = "localhost:9000/registry";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
JSONObject registrationDetails = new JSONObject();

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
registrationDetails.put("name", "OrderGenerator");
registrationDetails.put("uri", "http://localhost:8081/generate");
HttpEntity<String> request = 
new HttpEntity<String>(registrationDetails.toString(), headers);

String response = restTemplate.postForObject(registrationUrl,request,String.class);
System.out.println(response);
 }

};
```

i have called that method in the main class as follows as i want it to execute when i start the server,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OrderGeneratorServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    SpringApplication.run(OrderGeneratorServiceApplication.class, args);
    Registration.postRegistration();
}
```

my compiler doesnt, not show any errors but i do not receive notifications to the url i provided, However it starts to work when i send the POST request through postman. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postman, it creates auto generated code for the requests you are making. Its On the right hand side right below the "SAVE" button. You need to create your own auto format method so that you can give the correct input. Here is an example from some API that I am currently consuming.

You see how I have a super long input for the third line? You should create a method that will take your input and auto format it.

```
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                        .build();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\r\n  \"categoryName\": \"PostMan\",\r\n  \"categoryQuestions\": [\r\n    \"When is the last time you experienced nostalgia?\",\r\n    \"What's the scariest dream you've ever had?\",\r\n    \"What's the weirdest thought you've ever had?\",\r\n    \"What's the first thing that comes to mind when you hear the word fidget?\",\r\n    \"What made-up word would you incorporate into the English language if you could?\"\r\n  ]\r\n}");
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/categories")
                        .method("POST", body)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Here is my example (I am working with JSON Data in the format like this

```
{
  "categoryName": "PostMan",
  "categoryQuestions": [
    "When is the last time you experienced nostalgia?",
    "What's the scariest dream you've ever had?",
    "What's the weirdest thought you've ever had?",
    "What's the first thing that comes to mind when you hear the word fidget?",
    "What made-up word would you incorporate into the English language if you could?"
  ]
}
```

This is how I formatted that data.

```
public static String inputParse(String nameInput, ArrayList<String> questionInput) {
        String inputBuilder = "{\r\n  \"categoryName\": \"" + nameInput + "\",\r\n  \"categoryQuestions\": [\r\n    ";
        for (int i = 0; i < questionInput.size(); i++)
        {
            inputBuilder += "\"" + questionInput.get(i) + "\"";
            if (i != questionInput.size()-1)
            {
                inputBuilder += ",";
            }
        }
        inputBuilder += "\r\n  ]\r\n}";
        return inputBuilder;
    }
```

In addition, I see that you are working with Springboot. You can use org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate (rest-template) to consume rest api. An example for using REST Template that i got from [this](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/06/spring-resttemplate-get-post-put-and-delete-example.html) website.

```
private void createEmployee() {

        Employee newEmployee = new Employee("admin", "admin", "admin@gmail.com");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Employee result = restTemplate.postForObject(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_ENDPOINT_URL, newEmployee, Employee.class);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: I am already using a RestTemplate, Is there an error with the way i passed the JSON string in my implementation? cause what i've done is almost the same except for that

Comment: I completely missed the postman code part, i added the okhttp dependeny and copy pasted the code, voila it worked! thanks for the help!